# BootStrap Breaks in IE8

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using Bootstrap 3 with a fixed header and few position realted properties in the page.

But the Application looks completely broken in Internet Explorer

[image]

It seems to be broken after Integrating the HTMLs into my Rails Application.

[Broken Link](http://99atoms.com/)

[HTMLs Link](http://play.mink7.com/noise/noise-html/)

Comment: StackOverflow requires you to post the code here, not just links. Also, please ensure that you've read http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-respondjs

Comment: Works fine for me in IE 8 : http://i.imgur.com/5TtrdhV.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is just suggestion. Because can't debug with out source. Comment all included 'js' and just check in IE. Because I thought this might be a happen because of the js issue